# PostgreSQL handling of full time zones for timetz data type

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to model opening hours of shops in a PostgreSQL table. They should be time zone aware but independent of daylight time savings. In other words 9am to 5pm should be the same in summer and winter time.

My approach is to use two timetz columns to store the opening and closing hours. However, I can't insert data using the full time zone specifications, e.g. `'04:05:06 America/New_York'`. It seems to work only for timestamptz columns with a full date, e.g. `'2003-04-12 04:05:06 America/New_York'`.

Am I missing something or is there another way to specify times that depend on a time zone and ignore daylight time savings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid the data type `time with time zone`, as you see, it is problematic.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) states:

> The type `time with time zone` is defined by the SQL standard, but the definition exhibits properties which lead to questionable usefulness.

Maybe you would be better off with two fields, a `time without time zone` and a time zone field.